# How to avoid other stack containers?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a chat widget that I've been having trouble with given the unique header. Finally figured out how to position the TextComposer at the base of the app and all looks great, however the ListView where the chat's occur overlaps the header after a certain number of text entries. I've been trying to figure out how to position the ListView.builder so that it stays below the header (_buildImage and _buildTopHeader) and doesn't overlap such as in the image below. Unfortunately I haven't been having any luck. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

[Header Overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu8f0.png)

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                _buildIamge(),
                _buildTopHeader(),
                Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: new ListView.builder(
                      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      reverse: true,
                      itemBuilder: (_, int index) => _messages[index],
                      itemCount: _messages.length,
                    )),
              ]),
            ),
            Container(
              decoration:
              new BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).cardColor),
              height: 50.0,
              child: _buildTextComposer(),
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding:false,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Stack` renders its children list in order from top to bottom, with stuff on the bottom rendered over things at the top (it makes sense, I promise). So if you want the `ListView` to be rendered at the bottom of everything else, put it at the top of the children list:

```dart
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: new ListView.builder(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        reverse: true,
        itemBuilder: (_, int index) => _messages[index],
        itemCount: _messages.length,
      ),
    ),
    _buildIamge(),
    _buildTopHeader(),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was going for as I didn't want the text to clip under the header, just stop at the header but honestly knowing that it renders from top to bottom helps immensely as I don't realllly care if it clips under the header as you can just pull the widget down to see the hidden messages anyways if need be so this works for me. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Take a try with `Positioned`

**Demo:**

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StackPositionPage extends StatefulWidget {
  StackPositionPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _StackPositionPageState createState() => _StackPositionPageState();
}

class _StackPositionPageState extends State<StackPositionPage> {
  var _headerHeight = 100.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: buildBody(context),
    );
  }

  Widget buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
              _buildIamge(),
              _buildTopHeader(),
              Positioned(
                top: _headerHeight,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  itemBuilder: (_, int index) => Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: _buildMessage(index),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            height: 50.0,
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Center(
              child: Text("Composer"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Text _buildMessage(int index) => Text("Message " + (index + 1).toString());

  Container _buildTopHeader() {
    return Container(
      height: _headerHeight,
      color: Colors.pink,
      child: Center(
        child: Text("Header"),
      ),
    );
  }

  Container _buildIamge() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.grey,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You never have an element of your UI positioned at a specific pixel location (unless this is specifically what you're going for in e.g. a painting app). Otherwise you're setting your app up to have broken layout on every device other than the one you're developing on.

Comment: 100 pixels is sample, you can make header's height by percent of Screen or something else...

Comment: What height it needs to be depends on the content of the header, not some arbitrary pixel count or screen size percentage. It's much better to use a layout widget that eliminates the need for that entirely. In your case, since you have a rectangular header, why not just use a `Column`? Also keep in mind that OP's header is _not_ rectangular, so this approach would either still cause overlap or cause the messages to clip on nothing.